# How to interpret interactions involving quadratic terms in a GLM?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, interaction, negative-binomial-distribution, quadratic-form

I'm trying to interpret the output of a GLM from a [tutorial](https://rpubs.com/dwarton/68823) that models species abundances as a function of environmental data and species traits.

The function `traitglm` comes from the `mvabund` package and in the author's words:

> "It takes three arguments: L; R; and Q, and uses these to construct a
> regression model for abundance (L) as a function of additive terms for
> each variable in R and Q, quadratic terms for any continuous
> covariates (such as Weber’s length), and interaction terms between
> environmental and trait variables."

Here's the code for the model:

```
library(mvabund)
data(antTraits) # Load data
ft=traitglm(antTraits$abund,antTraits$env,antTraits$traits,method="manyglm") 
ft$fourth # print fourth corner terms
```

And here's the author's note on how to interpret the coefficients:

> "Because all predictors are standardised, you can interpret the size of
> coefficients as a measure of importance. As interaction terms, the
> fourth coefficients each have an interpretation as the amount by which
> a unit (1 sd) change in the trait variable changes the slope of the
> relationship between abundance and a given environmental variable.
> (But not that there are quadratic terms in the model too, which makes
> it a little messier to interpret, a plot would be a good idea.) So for
> example, one of the strongest interactions seems to be between
> Pilosity and Canopy cover - when there is more canopy cover, ants tend
> to have lower pilosity scores (less hairy)."

**I'm confused by the last sentence, because the coefficient is based on a quadratic function of canopy cover which is a continuous variable.**

Here's the full set of results in case you can't run the model:

```
results <- structure(c(-0.00534511447773003, -0.0447629598020786, 0.106170620522886, 
0.156827334590098, 0.114907563126611, 0.104301091980924, 0.0495441802223576, 
0.0883899778038507, -0.0337263993908883, -0.0561717751546072, 
0.278956272132365, 0.216643904693244, -0.061217876467139, 0.0548056188010987, 
0.0357985850266346, 0.0865376639056529, -0.084668676986989, -0.0889573039665969, 
0.210179645850993, 0.243034306663744, 0.143412679809558, 0.0343629954232624, 
0.0328636340019757, -0.0484200427818454, 0.166704472957665, -0.119947322629352, 
0.321139481278101, 0.273490092239953, 0.198330953622823, -0.0192768490596816, 
-0.00916876109019902, -0.0148181631062852, -0.0259056584320059, 
0.0396076363521851, 0.0390951350868973, 0.0436559367092447, 0.0674481033620884, 
0.0790378396927535, 0.0290644391611984, -0.0548418395761887), dim = c(8L, 
5L), dimnames = list(c("Femur.length", "No.spines", "Pilosity1", 
"Pilosity2", "Pilosity3", "Polymorphism1", "Polymorphism2", "Webers.length"
), c("Bare.ground", "Canopy.cover", "Shrub.cover", "Volume.lying.CWD", 
"Feral.mammal.dung")))
```

Comment: The `ft$fourth` here differs from that in the [tutorial](https://rpubs.com/dwarton/68823), which reports values for the reference levels ("0") of `Pilosity` and `Polymorphism` that don't show up in your results. (Maybe intercept was omitted.) You can specify "the amount by which a unit (1 sd) change in the trait variable [pilosity] changes the slope of the relationship between abundance and a given environmental variable [Canopy.cover]," but with a quadratic you need to know the baseline around which the 1 sd change was evaluated, and that matrix entry would change with that baseline choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a point of confusion on my part. The regression model shown in equation two of the below-referenced paper that the package is built on shows the interactions are between the linear terms for trait and environment and not the quadratics.

> Brown, A. M., Warton, D. I., Andrew, N. R., Binns, M., Cassis, G., &
> Gibb, H. (2014). The fourth‐corner solution–using predictive models to
> understand how species traits interact with the environment. Methods
> in Ecology and Evolution, 5(4), 344-352.